# Mac Pro | Can I listen to two audio sources, each on a separate jack?

Tags: itunes, audio, sound-card, mac

My iTunes library plays out of the rear audio jack on my 2007 Mac Pro tower (MacPro1,1 // Snow Leopard).  I'd like to have the front jack with headphones exclusively available for other sounds (usually browser-based videos, etc.)

Do I need a separate audio card?  Any suggestions on an inexpensive option?

Comment: Buying an iPod (or anything similar) seems like a lot less complicated solution to me!

Comment: Perhaps, but that's another rather expensive device and synch process I neither need nor want.  And it cannot hold my entire music collection.  It would be far more convenient to control music as I already do with iTunes on the Mac Pro.  I just want the ability to use headphones on the Pro on occasion and still allow iTunes to play over the home sound system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would spring for an airport express base station (less than $100 I believe).  It is an Apple Wifi access point with an audio out jack.  Itunes has an option to stream its output to that jack which you would then connect to your home stereo via the same sort of cable you are using to connect to the back of the tower now.

This way, your music through iTunes is separate from your 'computer sounds.'  I use this setup, in conjuction with a nice remote to play back all my music in my apartment.

http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/

Comment: Killer recommendation, Brad -- I just bought one for $55 (new). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a second audio card, but this will be a difficult thing to establish, because you also need media software which has a option for choosing which audio card where and when to use.